# Dockable MirrorMap plugin in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I tried to install Dockable MirrorMap plugin in QGIS 3.16, but it says not compatible. Is there any body have answer if there is any similar plugin as Dockable MirrorMap in QGIS 3.x versions?

Comment: Indeed, the [Dockable MirrorMap](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DockableMirrorMap/) plugin is only supported in QGIS 1 & 2. If you want, you may try update the plugin by your self (it will be highly appreciated by developers and community), see https://gisforthought.com/updating-a-plugin-from-qgis-2-to-qgis-3/ for more details.